# XML array from SQLite database

Tags: android

I am using SQLite to store school classes.  I want to fill in a Spinner with the classes that get stored in the database.  How would I grab all the classes in the DB and load them into a spinner?

Comment: Is SQLite running on Android ?

Comment: Yea the SQLite is running on the android.

Comment: You don't want to put more than a handful of strings into a spinner or it will quickly become unusable. If you have so many classes that you need to store them in a database, it may not be a good fit. On the other hand, if you only have a few, perhaps it is enough to just use preferences: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: First off, thanks for the responses.  It will only be a few classes and I am using a database just because that was the first thing I found for storage and I don't have time to go back and change all my code for the preferences.  So is there a way to query the classes out of the database and add them to the spinner?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Use `query()` or `rawQuery()` to get a `Cursor` with the results of a query on your database.

Step #2: Wrap the `Cursor` in a `CursorAdapter`, set to populate rows with your database results.

Step #3: Attach the `CursorAdapter` to the `Spinner`.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) showing using a `CursorAdapter` with a database query, but for a `ListView`. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) showing using a `CursorAdapter` with a Spinner, but from a query against a content provider, not a database.